# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

Below is my add button code, every time I click add button give this error

`command.ExecuteNonQuery();` can help me with the problem?

Here is my code

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Add button
        {
            tbLecturerId.Select();

            string strID, strFirstName, strUsername, strPassword, strDepartment, strEmail;

            strID = tbLecturerId.Text;
            strFirstName = tbLname.Text;
            strUsername = Usernametxt.Text;
            strPassword = Passwordtxt.Text;
            strDepartment = cbDepartment.Text;
            strEmail = tbEmail.Text;


            connect.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Lecturer_tbl (LecturerID,LecturertName, Username,Password, Department,Email) VALUES('" + strID + "','" + strFirstName + "','" + strUsername + "', '" + strPassword + "','" + strDepartment + "' ,'" + strEmail + "')", connect);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connect.Close();

            displayLectureGrid();
            clearLecturertbl();
```

Comment: Paste the exception stack trace there's no way to guess the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space and comma problem in your statement. Try this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Lecturer_tbl (LecturerID,LecturertName,Username,Password,Department,Email) VALUES('" + strID + "','" + strFirstName + "','" + strUsername + "','" + strPassword + "','" + strDepartment + "','" + strEmail + "')", connect);
```